# Swift Process() instance in Linux don't delete pipe file

Tags: swift

I need to execute some Linux command from swift 4.1 in Ubuntu 16.04. I use code:

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = pathToCommand

let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
```

Everything works perfect. But during executing the code, pipe-file created and don't removed after code completed. How to remove pipe-file after code completed?